# How can my website retrieve my Facebook page Live Videos?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook

If I go to the Graph API Explorer, get a User Access Token, and then go to `/<page-id>/live_videos` I can return a list of live videos from that page, including the status (VOD aka past, or LIVE) and the embed_html.

This is great but the problem is this User Access Token will expire. I want to be able to get this data as part of my website to show visitors whether we are live or not, and if so give them an option to open the video right there on the site. It shouldn't be something a user has to login in to allow my app to access FB on their behalf.

So I tried using an App Access Token which I got by using the App ID and App Secret of my page's 'Facebook App' as described in the [Facebook docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens)... but the Token that I get from this does not work; it tells me `A user access token is required to request this resource.`

Why must I get a ***User*** Access Token when it's my ***App*** (aka my website) that wants the data?

Honestly I didn't think it would be hard to get this information since it is a completely public page; I would have guessed you don't even need to authenticate, but probably just some need sort of identifying token for your app for rate limiting, etc. Is there any method like that?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/live_videos/: _"To read Live Videos your app will need: A Page Access Token."_ (Which obviously means you will want to do this part server-side only.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. So bottom-line is: at some point someone's going to have to actually log in to some backend page through a browser? There is no way to get a Page Token server side without an admin going through the browser login flow?

If I'm understanding this, though, an app can get a 'permanent' Page Token as quoted from the docs: "To get a longer-lived page access token, exchange the User access token for a long-lived one, as above, and then request the Page access token. The resulting page access token will not have any expiry time."

Comment: Correct. But be aware, page access tokens can be invalidated for other reasons - for example if the page admin that granted it changes their password (or loses page admin access, obviously.) Maybe check for exceptions on your API calls, and set up an email notification in case that happens (or something else goes wrong) ... something like that.